# Print timestump in Message Format

Tags: java, timestamp

OK i am trying to print a jtable and i want on footer message to print the time date  how i can make it this real

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {                                         
     MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("ΟΜΑΔΕΣ ΚΛΑΣΕΙΣ");
     String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   //MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat('SimpleDateFormat);
     MessageFormat footer = new 
     MessageFormat("SimpleDateFormat{yyyyMMddHHmmss,String}");
      try
       {
          jTable_Userss.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);  
       }
      catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e)
       {
           System.err.format("Cannot print %$%n",e.getMessage());
       }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests  I found the answer

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("ΟΜΑΔΕΣ ΚΛΑΣΕΙΣ");
         //String TimeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

           Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
               int month =cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               int year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               int day =cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Date "+year+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+day);
           // MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Page{0,number,integer},"  );
            try {
                jTable_Userss.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);


            } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e){
                System.err.format("Cannot print %$%n",e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("Report");

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

int month =cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int day =cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

MessageFormat footer = new MessageFormat("Date "+year+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+day+"Page{0,number,integer});

try {
    jTable_Userss.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer);
} catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e){
    System.err.format("Cannot print %$%n",e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very helpful. A description of what your change does is suggested.